# Running Cython Scripts from C# Process

Tags: c#, python, cython

I am running a python library from my C# application using `System.Diagnostics.Process` as follow

```
    Process p = new Process(); 
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "python";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "script_path";
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    StreamReader s = p.StandardOutput;
    String output = s.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
```

The library contains some ".pyx" files, which seem not recognized by the  code above, as I get this error:

```
The imported module "some module in .pyx" can not be found
```

When I run the python project from the cmd it runs correctly, is not the C# process supposed to do the same?

Comment: Are `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` environment variables (essentially) the same in both cases?

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Yes, they're the same.

Comment: `.pyx` files need to be compiled, have you built the library, ie are there `.so` files with the same name as the `.pyx` files in your path?

Comment: @BiRico I am running on windows, so there are ".pyd" files

Comment: can you run the same script from console?